# Set TemplateRef value from component

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am using a third party plugin "angular-mention", Which is taken a template the following ways.

```
<ng-template #mentionListTemplate let-item="item">
  <div class="media">
    <img class="mr-3" src="{{item.avatar}}" alt="" width="30" height="30">
    <div class="media-body text-right">
      <h6 class="mt-0 mb-0">{{item.name}}</h6>
      <small>@{{item.username}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The template is bind this way.

`<textarea [mentionListTemplate]="mentionListTemplate"</textarea>`

My problem is, I have lots of angular mention setting with textarea, every place needs mentionListTemplate so it is very much difficult to manage template setting for all places. Now I want to provide this mentionListTemplate from one place by using service or directive.

How could I pass mentionListTemplate from the component ? Thanks.

Comment: just edit your code a bit so ppl can see the first line of your <ng-template>. I think you just need to add a linebreak after first three backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a reusable component with input parameter for `item`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-textarea',
  template: `
    <textarea [mentionListTemplate]="mentionListTemplate"></textarea>
    <ng-template #mentionListTemplate let-item="item">
      <div class="media">
        ...
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class TextareaComponent  {
  @Input() item: IItem = { /* some default value */ };
}
```

So you can easily use it in other components:
`<app-textarea [item]="someItem"></app-textarea>`

p.s. also you can extend this component and create custom form control by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. In this case your textarea will behave like a usual form control element. For more details, checkout [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: Textarea is not containing the only mention tag, It has some other configuration so need to keep out from this app-textarea component. How could I do that?

Comment: can you provide another example of textarea usage with some other configs?

Comment: Full configuration of my textarea <textarea id="new-comment" #content title="{{ 'comments.form.fields.response.label' | translate }}" placeholder="{{ 'comments.form.fields.response.placeholder' | translate }}" rows="1"
              formControlName="content" autosize
                    emojiPicker
                    [mentionListTemplate]="mentionListTemplate"
                    (blur)="trimIfEmpty()"></textarea>

Comment: you could pass all those parameters to the component and optionally set them to the textarea field

Comment: I know this way. but this is not possible to my application.